# Connect SELECT AVG and UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql-update, average

i have a little problem. I use phpMyAdmin.

Thats my try:

```
SELECT AVG (ws_spiel_berechnung.note) as Test
FROM ws_spiel_berechnung 
LEFT JOIN ws_spieler
ON ws_spiel_berechnung.spieler_id = ws_spieler.id
INNER JOIN ws_spiel ON ws_spiel.id = ws_spiel_berechnung.spiel_id
where ws_spiel.spieltyp = 'Ligaspiel' and ws_spieler.id = 6875;
update ws_spieler set note_anpassung = Test where id = 6875
```

I want to take the `AVG(ws_spiel_berechnung.note)` to `ws_spieler.note_anpassung`. For example the result from `SELECT AVG` is 2,46. Now 2,46 should be updated to `note_anpassung`. But this doesn't work (i think because of the "Test").

Another question: The id is just an example. I want this for every id (it beginns at id 1 und ends at id 1000). The target is that i have the AVG note from every id at `"ws_spieler.note_anpassung"`.

I use google and this site, but i don't understand it. I would be happy if you can help me. And sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think you can do what you want with a correlated subquery:

```
update ws_spieler s 
     set s.note_anpassung = (select avg(sp.note)
                             from ws_spiel_berechnung sp
                             where sp. spieler_id = s.id
                            )
     where  s.spieltyp = 'Ligaspiel' and s.id = 6875;
```

Comment: That looks good, but i have one problem:
'Ligaspiel' is from "ws_spiel". There must be a check, if ws_spiel_berechnung.id = ws_spiel.id AND ws_spiel.typ = 'Ligatyp'

Do you understand? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, it's me again. I have still the same problem.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!